# how to get an email address passed in url

Tags: php

I have an email address passed as a variable in the url as part of the link. I need to be able to retrieve this email address and then insert it into a database.
the issue is i cannot seem to be able to retrieve the email address from the url. This is the code Im using to get it:

```
if(isset($GET['email'])){
 $email = $_GET['email'];
 }
```

The url looks something like this `www.sumwebsite.com?email=aemail@email.com`
Any ideas? As far as I have been able to see my code is right, so I am at a complete loss as to why it is not working.

Comment: `$GET` should be `$_GET`.

Comment: And whenever fruitlessly looking for missing variables without any PHP hints, the habitual `isset` should be omitted.

Comment: `if(isset($GET['email'])){` - **$GET** syntax copy/paste error perhaps? I'm not falling for that one, not again. lol

Comment: It certainly is better to transfer something sensitive like an email address via a POST request, not GET.

Comment: For argument's sake, try this instead `if(isset($_GET['email'])){`

Comment: @arkascha: How is an email address necessarily "sensitive" and how does a POST make it more secure?

Comment: @David an email address is a personal information and thus worth not being shown in public. Using POST makes one big difference: it does not show up in the servers log files...

Comment: Well `ALL`, I was soOOooo right about this one. Now **how did I ever guess** that one? It's questions like this, that Opens up a Great Big **CAN 'o WORMS**. Didn't fool me this time. **Consult comment #3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($GET['email'])){
          ^-- missing a _
```

should be

```
if(isset($_GET['email'])){
          ^---note the _
```

Comment: See, I could've easily answered it the same way, but if I do recall, there was a similar issue a week or so ago, where I think you gave an answer, to which and without seeing the OP's full code, ended up not working, and the answer was downvoted. So it's classic case of "Fool me once, shame on you. Fool me TWICE, shame on ME". Nope, not going to give out any more answers, before I see "full code".

Comment: @michi That's just so **WRONG**. And maybe because he was the **FIRST**, perhaps?

Comment: @michi actually I take that back and run this one by you instead. I meant he was the **first one** with the **CORRECT** answer.

Comment: Marc, I'm going to upvote your answer, and make things right.

Comment: @fred: no biggie. I think I can somehow, painfully, regretfully, withstand that massive -2 point hit. "ouch".

Comment: @MarcB lol yes, I know what you mean. I read between "those lines". Cheers

Comment: @michi **FYI**: The reason to give an **answer**, is to keep it out of the **unanswered** questions section, if and when someone supplies a "correct" answer. It's a classic **2+2** equation, with a **dash** of common sense.

Answer (score -1):

When you create the link with the email you should [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it.
When you get it from PHP with **$_GET** you should [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it.

**EDIT**

As said in the comments, $_GET already transparently run urldecode(), so it's not needed.
The urlencode() it's indeed needed.
Also, the author made the error of using $GET instead of $_GET.

Comment: ahem.. take a closer look at the OP's syntax ;-)

Comment: take a closer look to my answer ($_GET)... :-)

Comment: You know that, and I know that, but your answer doesn't say where the error was.

Comment: you are right. But with my answer I'm concentrating on another (IMHO bigger!!) error made by the question's author, where the '@' sign is not protected with url encoding. Please check RFC3986 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), and search for "reserved"

Comment: You have a point there indeed ;-) Well, no one downvoted you, which is a good thing. If it does get downvoted, rest assured it won't be me. Let's hope the operative word is not "yet".

Comment: You don't need to call `urldecode()` explicitly, PHP does that automatically when parsing query parameters.

Comment: @dAm2K **Key-riced**, looks like I spoke too soon.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! however, unfortunately I have no control over how the email gets set in the URL.

Comment: @Fred :-) I read http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php where they say that "The GET variables are passed through urldecode()."

Comment: @dAm2K Oh, I'm not arguing that, not arguing at all, someone else did. I consider myself just an "innocent bystander", eating his Bag 'o Chips on a streetcorner. Hopefully, not get hit by a runaway BEER Truck!

Comment: @dAm2K I would suggest though, that you edit your answer about the fact that, the OP forgot the "underscore" between the `$` and `GET` ;-)